# Problem with java3d

Tags: ubuntu, java, troubleshooting

I want to play this java simulation: http://www.compadre.org/OSP/items/detail.cfm?ID=9640 in java 3d mode on a linux (ubuntu) system. But it doesn't work.

If I switch to java 3d-mode it complains that java 3d is not installed.  `sudo aptitude install libjava3d-java` didn't help.

Then I did a right click in this java app and selected Diagnostics-> About Java 3D. Then I get the message:

> Java 3D was not found in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext

Then I tried

```
cp /usr/share/java/*3d* \
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext`
```

but I get the same error message again.

I start the java app like this:

```
java -jar ejs_astronomy_SolarLunarEclipse.jar
```

I tried this on two systems, one freshly installed and also switched from openjdk to sun-jdk temporarily without any effect.

Any idea how I can get this work?

Answer (score 1):

[Java 3D](http://java3d.java.net/) is not included in the JRE or JDK.

Some instructions for installing on Ubuntu are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java3dUbuntu